# Kubernetes federation - unable to deploy the federation control plane

Tags: kubernetes

I am working on creating a federation with three clusters. The host cluster spin up but I am not able to init the federation successfully.

```
kubefed init Inkubefed --host-cluster-context=default-context --dns-provider="coredns" --dns-zone-name="example.com." --dns-provider-config="/root/coredns-provider.conf"
Creating a namespace federation-system for federation system components... done
Creating federation control plane service...............................................................................
.......................................................................
```

The "creating federation control place service step takes a lot of time and didn't stop loading unless i forced it"

The host cluster has 3 controllers and 2 workers and some egdes;

I'm using coredns as DNS provider : I followed exactly the instructions available here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/federation/set-up-coredns-provider-federation/ ; coredns and etcd operator are up and running ! 
NB : i have also a kubedns service running on my cluster

Kubernetes version : 1.9.2 
kubefed version : v1.9.0-alpha.3
Any hints please where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I would bet that `kubefed` has a `--v` option just like most of the kubernetes CLIs; can you try `kubefed --v=100` and see if that helps, and/or post a pastebin of its output?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem(my deployment was on bare-metal). The issue was that there is no loadbalancer implementation on non-cloud environments.

Comment: use this option --api-server-service-type="NodePort"; it will solve your problem